# Executing part of the code once in cuda

Tags: c, cuda

I was wondering if it's possible to do a static statement in the GPU

this is part of my code

```
__global__ void run_state(float *oldv, float* newv, float* w, int t)
{
  int i = threadIdx.x;

  nextState(i, oldv, newv, w, t);


  newv[0]   = newv[1];
  newv[N+1] = newv[N];

}
```

I was wondering if  `newv[0]   = newv[1];` and `newv[N+1] = newv[N];` can be executed after `nextState` has looped and only execute once ?

Comment: Currently, there is no efficient synchronization between all threads of grid. I suggest to do each loop iteration by one kernel launch. Notice that you ***do not need*** to copy data back to host at each iteration (kernel launch).

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear to me what exactly you want to achieve (execute once *per what*?), so I'll show some alternatives:

If you want to execute a statement once **per block**, you can do that simply by testing the thread index:

```
__syncthreads();
if ((threadIdx.x | threadIdx.y | threadIdx.z) == 0) {
    // statements that are only executed once per block
}
__syncthreads();
```

If you want to execute a statement once **per kernel invocation**, you need to be a bit more specific about when the statement shall execute, as the blocks of a kernel execute in no particular order.

Simple extension of the above example yields a version where the statement executes once per kernel invocation, but at an unspecified time:

```
if ((threadIdx.x | threadIdx.y | threadIdx.z
     | blockIdx.x | blockIdx.y | blockIdx.z) == 0) {
    // statements that are executed once per kernel invocation,
    // at an unspecified time
}
```

It is possible to specify when the statement shall execute using atomic operations in global memory, at the expense of additional global memory bandwidth use. To limit the performance impact, it is usually a good idea to perform these atomic operations only once per block.

If you want to execute the statement **as soon as the first block reaches it**, a simple test of a global flag is sufficient:

```
__global__ volatile unsigned int statementHasExecuted;

...

__syncthreads();
if ((threadIdx.x | threadIdx.y | threadIdx.z) == 0) {
    unsigned int state = atomicMin((unsigned int*)&statementHasExecuted, 1);
    if (state == 0) {
        // statements that are executed once per kernel invocation,
        // as soon as the first block reaches the statement

        // now make the results visible to the other blocks:
        __threadfence();
        // and signal that we are done:
        atomicMin((unsigned int*)&statementHasExecuted, 2);
    } else {
        while (state < 2) {
            // busy wait until execution of statement in other block has finished:
            state = statementHasExecuted;
        }
    }
}
__syncthreads();
```

`statementHasExecuted` would need to be reset to zero before every kernel launch.

What you are after might be the opposite case, a piece of code that is only executed **after all other blocks have finished**. [Appendix B.5 "Memory Fence Functions" of the Programming Guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#memory-fence-functions) gives example code for this.

(Note that all code has been written in the browser and is untested - it may contain errors).

Answer (score 0):

You designate one thread to do the final work. For instance:

```
__global__ void run_state(float *oldv, float* newv, float* w, int t)
{
  int i = threadIdx.x;

  nextState(i, oldv, newv, w, t);

  if (i == 0) {
    newv[0]   = newv[1];
    newv[N+1] = newv[N];
  }
}
```

Comment: Presumably `nextState(...)` is altering `newv` somehow so we may want a `__syncthreads()` before we update `newv`. It's also worth noting that this solution will not work if we're using multiple blocks.